# How to make panels to navigate left and right on click of button in Sencha ExtJs

Tags: extjs, panel

I have created 3 panels,2 buttons(Prev,next) in Extjs and added to viewport.
At a time only one panel should visible (by default first panel).
On click of next button it should display next panel,then if i click on "prev" button it should display the previous panel.

Now i have wrote a code for panels and its working as ,panels are not navigating to left and right properly.

Here is my code :

```
Ext.application({
name: 'HelloExt',
requires: [
'Ext.util.Point' 

 ],
launch: function() {

 var button =Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Toggle Containers',
    handler: function () {      

    if (this.clickCount==1) {            
        containerPanel1.getEl().scrollRight; 
        containerPanel2.getEl().slideIn('t', 'toggle');
        this.clickCount=2;

    } else {

        this.clickCount = 1;            
        containerPanel1.getEl().slideIn('t', 'toggle');
        containerPanel2.getEl().scrollLeft;

        }

    }, 
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
}); 


var containerPanel1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
draggable: {
      insertProxy: false,

      startDrag: function(e) {
        var el = Ext.get(this.getEl());
        el.dd = new Ext.dd.DDProxy(el.dom.id, 'group');
        this.x = el.getLeft(true);
        this.y = el.getTop(true);           
      },          

      afterDrag: function(e) {
          this.x = el.getLeft(true);
          this.y = el.getTop(true);
          this.fireEvent('itemdrag', this);

      }
    },
width:400,
height:550,    
layout: 'column',
bodyStyle:{'background-color':'blue'},
margin:'30 0 0 20', 
suspendLayout: true ,   
defaults :{
xtype: 'panel',
margin:'30 0 0 0',
height: 450,
columnWidth: 0.2
},

 items: [
    {
        html: 'Child Panel 1',            
    },
    {           
        html: 'Child Panel 2',          
    },
    {          
        html: 'Child Panel 3',          
    },
    {            
        html: 'Child Panel 4',          
    },
    {           
        html: 'Child Panel 5',          
    }
]
      });

containerPanel1.draggable;

var containerPanel2 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
draggable: {
      insertProxy: false,

      startDrag: function(e) {
        var el = Ext.get(this.getEl());
        el.dd = new Ext.dd.DDProxy(el.dom.id, 'group');
        this.x = el.getLeft(true);
        this.y = el.getTop(true);           
      },          
          afterDrag: function(e) {
          this.x = el.getLeft(true);
          this.y = el.getTop(true);
          this.fireEvent('itemdrag', this);

      }
    },
width:400,
height:550,  
layout: 'column',
bodyStyle:{'background-color':'green'},
margin:'30 0 0 20', 
suspendLayout: true ,   
defaults :{
xtype: 'panel',
margin:'30 0 0 0',
height: 300,
columnWidth: 0.2
},  
 items: [           
    {      
        html: 'Child Panel 1',            
    },
    {            
        html: 'Child Panel 2',          
    },
    {           
        html: 'Child Panel 3',          
    },
    {            
        html: 'Child Panel 4',          
    },
    {           
        html: 'Child Panel 5',

    }
]
   });
     containerPanel2.draggable;
    containerPanel2.getEl().hide();

       Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
   layout: 'column',
    items: [containerPanel1,containerPanel2,button]

    }); 


    }
     });
```

Please help me..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was just building a similar project, so here's an example snippet you could use. Notice that you can change the amount and order of panels and the code will still work. The click handler simply looks for the visible panel first, and then depending on the direction attempts to either go forward or backward.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyViewport1', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    id: 'switchPanels',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height: 100,
                    html: 'this is panel 1',
                    title: 'My Panel A'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height: 100,
                    hidden: true,
                    html: 'this is panel 2',
                    title: 'My Panel B'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height: 100,
                    hidden: true,
                    html: 'this is panel 3',
                    title: 'My Panel C'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    switchPanel: function(forward) {
                        var p = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel(true){isVisible()}')[0]; // visible panel
                        var n = forward ? p.nextSibling('panel(true)') : p.previousSibling('panel(true)'); // closest sibling
                        if (n) { // don't let go past the last one
                            p.hide();
                            n.show();
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("can't go past the " + (forward ? 'end' : 'beginning'));
                        }
                    },
                    id: 'buttons',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            handler: function(button, event) {
                                button.up().switchPanel(false);
                            },
                            text: 'Prev'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            handler: function(button, event) {
                                button.up().switchPanel(true);
                            },
                            text: 'Next'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **card(Wizard) layout** for this. please refer `simple sample example` below.

Im sure this will help you to resolve your problem.

```
var active = 0;
var main = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    layout: 'card',
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Next',
        handler: function(){
            var layout = main.getLayout();
            ++active;
            layout.setActiveItem(active);
            active = main.items.indexOf(layout.getActiveItem());
        }
    }],
    items: [{
        title: 'P1'
    }, {
        title: 'P2'
    }, {
        title: 'P3',
        listeners: {
            beforeactivate: function(){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

**Please refer card(wizard) layout in the below link**.

```
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/layout-browser/layout-browser.html
```

Thanks